# How to get a list of active windows when using wayland

Tags: gnome, wayland

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.10 which uses Wayland instead of (or in some sort of combination?) X11. Before I could use `xprop -root|grep ^_NET_CLIENT_LIST` or wmctrl (`wmctrl -lpGxu`) to get a list of all active windows. This doesn't work any more with all gnome applications like the terminal and some others like nautlius. Is there any way to list those?

Comment: You can't. This stackoverflow question has more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465016/how-do-i-get-the-active-window-on-gnome-wayland#45758620

Answer (score 17):

## Update

Sadly, this [no longer works on Gnome 41 for security reasons](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/pneza1/gdbus_call_for_moving_windows_not_working_in/)

Running `global.context.unsafe_mode = true` in Looking Glass re-enables the functionality, but only temporarily.

## Original answer

Yeah, on Wayland, sadly Xorg utilities like `wmctrl` and `xdotool` do not function. Instead we can talk to the window manager.

For Gnome, we can run [`gdbus`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus.html) to send a DBUS message to execute some GJS ([JavaScript bindings for the GNOME C APIs](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/Writing)).

To get a list of windows, with their class and title (using `sed` and `jq` to prettify):

```bsh
$ gdbus call \
  --session \
  --dest org.gnome.Shell \
  --object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
  --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "      
    global              
      .get_window_actors()
      .map(a=>a.meta_window)                                   
      .map(w=>({class: w.get_wm_class(), title: w.get_title()}))" \
  | sed -E -e "s/^\(\S+, '//" -e "s/'\)$//" \
  | jq .
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "class": "firefox",
    "title": "Mozilla Firefox"
  },
  {
    "class": "org.gnome.Nautilus",
    "title": "Downloads"
  },
  {
    "class": "Google-chrome",
    "title": "ubuntu - Bash command to focus a specific window - Super User - Google Chrome"
  },
  {
    "class": "sublime_text",
    "title": "untitled (dotfiles) - Sublime Text"
  },
  {
    "class": "gnome-terminal-server",
    "title": "Projects"
  },
  {
    "class": "Gnome-shell",
    "title": "gnome-shell"
  }
]
```

To get the class of the currently focused window:

```bsh
$ gdbus call \
  --session \
  --dest org.gnome.Shell \
  --object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
  --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "
    global
      .get_window_actors()
      .map(a=>a.meta_window)
      .find(w=>w.has_focus())
      .get_wm_class()" \
  | cut -d'"' -f 2
gnome-terminal-server
```

You can play around with what's possible in GJS using Gnome's 'Looking Glass' debugger: Alt+F2, and run `lg`

Comment: The first `gdbus call` doesn't work for me on ubuntu 22.04, returns `(false, '')`

Comment: @smido Even after the `global.context.unsafe_mode = true`?

Comment: Sorry it works with that call before. Thanks