# GNOME: Select multiple windows

Tags: debian, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, multi-monitor, wayland

I'm a fullstack dev with a past in C and a current focus on Python and React. I'm not a sysAdmin but I've been using *nix systems since 1989 and I'm afraid of no dirty hands admin task.

## The UI problem

I'm using Debian 12 Bookworm on an LG Gram 14 (32GB RAM). This was installed last week (July 2023) from the original Debian download site. The current GNOME version is 43.6. Previously, I had Ubuntu 22.10 and 23.04 on the same machine and I still had this question, but I had other issues, so I moved into Debian and it's great.

I work with 5 workspaces (for now). Sometimes, I end up with a lot of windows opened (VS Code, different browsers, file managers, bash terminals, ...), where a lot means over 100. Every now and then, I need to move some of these windows across workspaces.

Moving these winodws means selecting them one by one and  doing <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> | <kbd>PgUp</kbd>.

##### Is there a way to select multiple windows and transfer these all at once?

I tried multiple approaches to this, in both the activities view and on the taskbar, including <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>, and pretty much every possible combination of clicking with multiple choices of <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> that one can try before vision starts getting blurry and viollence against hardware starts sounding like the best approach. I think that even <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> was thrown in, because why not?

Is there any GNOME extension That could help? Any secret key combination? Any prayer?

People keep telling me that I could do this easily... in Windows! Possible reactions on my end range from utterly ignoring these to more elaborate forms of extreme prejudice. If your suggestion comes with an `MS` label, please keep quiet and don't interrupt the grown ups.

## Alternative

If a suggestion comes in along the lines of script automation, this would be **extremely welcome**, too. I have a wide set of my daily / frequent tasks automated by script and I highly recommend this.

I tried [`xdotool`](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool), but this doesn't work for `Wayland` and `Xorg` gets a bit messy. There is a [`ydotool`](https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool), but it seems to be a very small subset of the previous one, and a [`dotool`](https://git.sr.ht/%7Egeb/dotool) that doesn't come in `.deb` format and I just don't feel like installing Go just to try out.

Comment: by the way, I'm not a GNOME user myself, so I can't really help you with experience, but: GNOME shell, i.e. the environment in which the whole interaction is scripted, runs on a JavaScript derivative. So, worst case, you would have to write a JavaScript-alike plugin – something that a react developer might not find that terrible.

Comment: Dear @MarcusMüller, I know about the Linux genesis, essentially because I was there. My point was that with all the common stuff — filesystem, shell, pipes, vi, make, gcc... — the intersection is huge. This is not exactly _Sapiens_ vs _Neanderthal_. Regarding Gnome and JS, I did not know that. Thank you! I see a lot of older stuff in C that did what I need under X11 / Xorg, but this new Wayland layer is what makes it all the worst.

Comment: In case you are looking for where to start, you need
[gcs](https://gjs.guide/), to write an
[extension](https://gjs.guide/extensions/development/creating.html#a-working-extension),
or look through the [contributed list](https://extensions.gnome.org/), such
as [right click
down](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1210/right-click-down/) with
code like
[this](https://gitlab.com/criztovyl/gnome-right-click-down/-/blob/master/rcd@criztovyl.space/convenience.js?ref_type=heads) which might need a metadata tweak.

Comment: You might have found it more palatable to code only small bits of JavaScript and
use
[gdbus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399753/how-to-get-a-list-of-active-windows-when-using-wayland/635740#635740)
to run them, but that is
[disabled](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/pneza1/gdbus_call_for_moving_windows_not_working_in/)
from Gnome 40, but you can still put the code in a mini extension and [call
that](https://gist.github.com/tuberry/dc651e69d9b7044359d25f1493ee0b39),
for now anyway.